# Signing gcrypt data returns 16777281

Tags: c++, gnupg, libgcrypt

I setup the following gcrypt code to first sign and then following that verify the data.
However, this already returns 16777281 as result of the signing operation.
But I couldn't find any error message that matches this.

Edit: Additional Info:

The error code through gcry_strerror results in "Invalid Object"

```
std::cout << gcry_check_version(nullptr) << std::endl;
gcry_control(GCRYCTL_SUSPEND_SECMEM_WARN);
gcry_control (GCRYCTL_INIT_SECMEM, 16384, 0);
gcry_control(GCRYCTL_RESUME_SECMEM_WARN);
gcry_control(GCRYCTL_INITIALIZATION_FINISHED, 0);

gcry_sexp_t keypair;

gcry_sexp_t params;

gcry_sexp_build(&params, nullptr, "(genkey (rsa (nbits 4:3072)))");

gcry_pk_genkey(&keypair, params);

assert(keypair != nullptr);
gcry_sexp_release(params);

gcry_sexp_t priv = gcry_sexp_find_token(keypair, "private-key", 0);
gcry_sexp_t pub = gcry_sexp_find_token(keypair, "public-key", 0);

assert(priv != nullptr);
assert(pub != nullptr);

gcry_sexp_t data;
gcry_sexp_t r_sig;

gcry_sexp_build(&data, nullptr, "(data (flags raw) (value (100, 2, 254, 88, 90, 45, 23))");

std::cout << gcry_pk_sign(&r_sig, data, priv)  << std::endl;
```

Comment: Did you try `gcry_strerror` to get a human-readable description of this error code? It's expected that you can't find this value anywhere; see [docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Error-Values.html).

Comment: I don't know anything about gcrypt, but commas are not used in s-expressions.

Comment: thanks @Thomas that brought me further. It says "Invalid object"

Comment: @Botje can you tell me how I would put an array of ints into an s-expression then? It was rather difficult to find good doc on how to put this together.

Comment: [the manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Cryptographic-Functions.html#Cryptographic-Functions) for the function you're trying to use says the argument must be passed "as an mpi", which corresponds to the %m or %M [format string specifier](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-S_002dexpressions.html#Working-with-S_002dexpressions)

Comment: The tests have an [example](https://github.com/gpg/libgcrypt/blob/master/tests/pubkey.c#L279)

Comment: ty, that helped a lot